# Index of first differing element without loop

Tags: python

I have two lists say

```
A = [1,3]
B = [1,3,5,6]
```

I want to know the index of the first differing element between these lists (2 in this case).

Is there a simple way to do this, or do I need to write a loop?

Comment: If they both are always sorted then there is a way w/o loops

Comment: Sorting is not guaranteed. What shortcut is there for sorted loops?

Comment: I don't think there is anything simpler than a straight forward loop over the lists, comparing the elements and keeping the track of the index. It is still a very simple solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps the loop you mentioned is the most obvious way, not necessarily the most pretty. Still every O(n) complexity solution is fine by me.

```
lesser_length = min(len(A), len(B))
answer = lesser_length # If one of the lists is shorter and a sublist, 
                       # this will be the answer, because the if condition
                       # will never be satisfied.
for i in xrange(lesser_length):
    if A[i] != B[i]:
        answer = i
        break
```

`range` instead of `xrange` in Python3. A generator would be the best way given that you don't know when the difference between lists will occur.(In Python2, `xrange` is generator. In Python3, `xrange` became the regular `range()` function.)

A list comprehension is also viable. I find this to be more readable.

Answer (score 5):

You can use following generator expression within `next()` function using `enumerate()` and `zip()` function:

```
>>> next(ind for ind,(i,j) in enumerate(zip(A,B)) if i != j)
2
```

Comment: This doesn't work if one list is a subset of the other.

Comment: You might want to clarify this condition by editing your question.